# How to use an own kernel configuration for a raspberry pi in yocto?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, yocto

I like to remove some unused drivers for my RPI2 + custom board. For that I am creating an own configuration via:

```
bitbake linux-raspberrypi -c menuconfig
```

and save the new kernel preset to the file `defconfig`.

After this I created an append file for the linux-raspberryp recipe.

So I created the file

```
linux-raspberrypi%.bbappend
```

and filled it with:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/linux-raspberrypi:"

SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"

PACKAGE_ARCH = "raspberrypi2"
```

I put the defconfig file to:

```
<meta-mylayer>/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi/raspberrypi2/defconfig
```

When recompiling the kernel via:

```
bitbake linux-raspberrypi -c clean
bitbake linux-raspberrypi
```

The standard RPI2 configuration is taken.

Any idea how to overcome this problem?
I am working on the "actual" pyro branch of meta-raspberrypi and yocto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, unfortunately, the easiest way is probably to patch the kernel source... Or copy your defconfig over the in kernel-tree one.

The `meta-raspberrypi` layer does some unfortunate things in their kernel recipes, and even though this has become better with time, they're still not really nice...

If you take a look at `recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi.inc`, the following lines explains the issue:

```
KERNEL_DEFCONFIG_raspberrypi2 ?= "bcm2709_defconfig"

do_kernel_configme_prepend() {
    install -m 0644 ${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs/${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG} ${WORKDIR}/defconfig || die "No default configuration for ${MACHINE} / ${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG} available."
}
```

Thus,they're copying the in-tree defconfig to `${WORKDIR}/defconfig`, thereby overwriting your own defconfig.

You in you `.bbappend`, you could try to add:

```
do_kernel_configme_prepend() {
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/defconfig ${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs/${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG} || die "No default configuration for ${MACHINE} / ${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG} available."
}
```

Thus, first overwriting the in-kernel-tree one with your own `defconfig`.

Comment: That line isn't there anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at how to use devtool to modify source code for the jethro:
http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-devtool-in-your-workflow

I would start by having a fork at the git repository that it is using;
http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-raspberrypi/tree/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi_4.9.bb

Using `devtool` in Yocto;
in your build directory: create a my-linux-raspberry folder;

```
mkdir linux-raspberry-test
devtool modify -x linux-raspberry ./my-linux-raspberry
```

This will put unpack the source code into `my-linux-raspberry` for you to modify;  It also create the git repository in there;

Then, modify the code in `my-linux-raspberry`;  To test build, run `devtool build linux-raspberry`;  Once you are satisfied, add this git repository to your fork;

```
git add .
git commit -m "my-linux-raspberry"
devtool update-recipe linux-raspberry
```

Optional: run `devtool reset linux-raspberry` to remove the bbappend file;